# Gldraw call asynchronous or not

Tags: opengl, vsync

When i call gldrawarrays with a large set of data will the function return only after drawing all the vertices or will it happen asynchronously b/w cpu and gpu?

Also how does vsync work. Aren't they related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `glDrawArrays` you queue that action in the GPU. It will get executed the next time you call `glFlush` which is also executed by the platform dependent `SwapBuffers` function.

VSync is a completely different thing. It synchronizes `SwapBuffers` with your monitors refresh rate to avoid 'tearing' artifacts. Tearing is when half of the screen was displayed with one frame and half of the screen with the next frame. This is perceived by the eye and can become ugly and annoying.

Comment: Can path tracing be implemented to render at real time??

Comment: These are very little questions that didn't fit to be a separate thread..that's why I Am commenting

Comment: When I call glflush..Will it return only after processing the draw call queue??

Comment: Ohhh...optimising cpu overhead is what all about Vulcan know. They ask is to write our own drivers??

Comment: @YashwanthCB This is a huge question that is probably too vague to answer. There are engines that do path tracing realtime, but when you need more detailed meshes it starts to be infeasible on current hardware. Yes `glFlush` returns only after processing the queue. No Vulcan is not about writing your own drivers, but pretty close because you are working on the minimum level required to make platform independency possible.

Comment: Oh I get it...about path tracing ...Are they anh raster graphic techniques to get results closely similar to path tracing??

Comment: @YashwanthCB That question is too vague to answer. Look at current top engines and see whether they can achieve it. Look at specific things you want to achieve and google them. There is a lot of research regarding 3D graphics so there might be some approaches already laid out that you can attempt.

Comment: http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AlexandruVoica/20140318/213148/Practical_techniques_for_ray_tracing_in_games.php this may help people like me

Answer (score 1):

When you give any draw command. The function returns its value immediately in next tick. You give "gldrawarrays" it tells gpu to draw all stuff. Cpu goes to the next command, while gpu is still drawing. note that cpu doesn't pause for the gpu to complete the drawing process.

That's one of the reason why we use delay function at end of code. We tell cpu to wait until gpu completes drawing ( I don't know which language you you are using so i cannot tell you exactly which command delays.)

Comment: Can multiple thread summit a draw call to single context?

Comment: How do find whether the draw call has finished its job?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942045/which-one-is-proper-method-of-writing-this-gl-code

Comment: Look at retro koradi answer. He has explained it in detail

Comment: Ohhh...optimising cpu overhead is what all about Vulcan know. They ask is to write our own drivers??

Comment: When I measure time for  glbufferdata what am I measuring actually?

Comment: You are measuring time taken by cpu to give instructions to gpu.